# Science fiction novel hacking passwords through key sounds

Tags: story-identification, novel

Read in the late 80s or early 90s, this was a science fiction novel that involved a young female prisoner being held in some sort of military RV. She had super sensitive hearing and hacked the guard's computer password by deciphering the marginal differences in the sounds made by the individual keyboard keys. They ended up having to have sex to protect themselves from a swarm of killer bees or hornets. The only other thing I think I recall is that the author was a teacher / professor of creative writing at a US? university and wrote the book as a bet with his/her students. I don't think it was Samuel R Delaney but could easily be wrong

Comment: I don't suppose you remember who the "they" was having sex? I'm assuming the prisoner was one, but it sounds like you have some idea of who the man (or woman) in this might be associated with them. I've seen some side references to *Cryptonomicon* (1999) doing password hacking through sound recordings, but nothing firm, and the other facts don't fit.

Comment: It wasn't sound recording in Cryptonomicon it was by picking up the electromagnetic radiation kicked off by monitor refresh, if memory serves.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, the couple having sex were the female prisoner and the guard; there was some suggestion that she controlled the bees in some way and would have been fine on her own. I can't recall either why she wanted to protect the guard or why the sex was supposed to protect them. Thanks for the Cryptonomicon suggestion but it's not that, as per Paul the major hacking technique in that was Van Eck phreaking. I've revised the timing slightly to be more late 80s rather than early 90s

Comment: Slowly working my way through this list of [Sci Fi scholars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_fiction_studies) to see if one of them might have written the book. No dice so far

Comment: This reminds me of one of David Drake's stories from *Lacey and his Friends* where the title character (male) hacks a PW by analyzing the wear on a keypad used only for entering a PW by a single person. I hink it weas the 3rd story "Underground". Clearly not a match, but related.

Comment: What is a *military RV*?

Comment: Military Recreation Vehicle as in mobile / off road capable vehicle used both for transport and to confine the prisoner

Comment: @DavidSiegel sorry for huge delay in replying. As you say, similar but not quite what I'm looking for. 99% sure the female prisoner could hear but not see the keyboard when the guard was using it. And she then used the minor key sound differences to enter the password successfully later on

Comment: From yesterday’s Guardian newspaper in the UK … “AI can identify passwords by sound of keys being pressed, study suggests” https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2023/aug/08/ai-could-identify-passwords-by-sound-of-keys-being-pressed-study-suggests